# Как web приложения определяют с какого устройства осуществляется вход

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookie

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. Понимаю, что вопрос не совсем связан с программированием. Пишу небольшой сайт на ASP MVC. На сайте есть раздел личного кабинета. Хочу повысить его безопасность, сделав при входе в этот личный кабинет проверку устройства с которого вход осуществляется. Вопрос - как в современных `web asp` (и не только) приложениях реализована подобная проверка ?  Какие подходы могут быть - определить IP или MAC или с использованием Cookeis ? Буду рад кусочку кода или просто теории.

[UPD] Имеет ли значение браузер с которого происходит вход?

Comment: Могу подтолкнуть в сторону почитать про `User agent`, возможно это удовлетворит ваш интерес

Comment: например в js есть `navigator.userAgent` и дальше рисуются костыли вроде  https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser/blob/master/src/bowser.js со списком  https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser/blob/master/src/useragents.js  ....... реализации разные конечно, но суть в одном - юзер агент

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin что именно такое `User agent` ?

Comment: MAC адрес не получишь, никак.

Comment: `headers` заголовки запроса, но их легко подделать, врядли сильно получиться с их помощью повысить безопастность, а вот чекть мак и ип, использовать куки это да

Comment: @IgorSergeevich мак, ип куки все вместе или это разные подходы ?

Comment: @Сергей гугл еще жив - *[что именно такое User agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent)*

Comment: куки это куки, отдельная вещь, определение ип имеет смысл если вы продумываете какую-то логику, по которой будете считать, представляет угрозу ип или нет. С мак сложнее, вы его так просто не возьмете, его заменяют куки как идентификатор устройства или подтверждения сессии

Comment: @IgorSergeevich правильно ли я понимаю, что если не определять IP адрес а ориентироваться на куки то любой кто скопирует с ПК файл Cookie сможет зайти ?

Comment: скорее да, но точно сказать не могу, куки храняться в базе браузера, я не пробовал копировать, возможно они шифруются

Comment: @IgorSergeevich тогда понятно почему после переустановке хрома при входе в личный кабинет приложение выдало предупреждение о том, что вход происходит с неизвестного устройства. Получается в таких случаях используют или IP или Cookies ?

Comment: И ип и куки используются, гуглите описание защиты фб и инстаграм